# Redirect & mask URL to Azure subdomain

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, dns, url-masking

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app running on Azure as `generic-site.co`. It's a white-label site that supports a number of subdomains: `acme.generic-site.co`, `globex.generic-site.co`, `initech.generic-site.co`, etc. Browsing to each of them changes branding on the pages, but the underlying functionality is exactly the same.

Meanwhile I have an external domain name `acme-site.com` hosted by GoDaddy. I want to redirect this specifically to the `acme.generic-site.co` subdomain, but I also want to maintain `acme-site.com` as the root URL for any further browsing on that site, allowing users to have a pure `acme` experience without any indication of the underlying `generic-site`-ness.

I've tried to do this using GoDaddy's Domain Forwarding with masking, but I ran into CSRF issues almost immediately.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I suspect IIS URL rewriting might be helpful, but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Domain Forwarding with masking.
Just add custom domain `acme-site.com` to Azure Web App.

And you may need to do one of the following:

- Add a middleware or something that change `Host` in HTTP request header from
  `acme.generic-site.co` to `acme-site.com`.
- Adjust the application to
  load correct branding when using domain `acme-site.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to use IIS Url Rewrite module as you mentioned in your question. There are several examples on how to do this. Please start with this post by Scott Forsyth: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one